# Prevent all "debugger" calls from pausing javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, javascript-debugger

I don't like `debugger`. It's a risky piece of code to be adding into an application.

If this is accidentally left in the application prior to a live deployment, then the script will pause when developer tools are open.

Is there a cross-browser way of preventing `debugger` from pausing the code?

Then this could be configured so that `debugger` only pauses when the application is in development mode.

Comment: You shouldn't keep `debugger` in the files after development imo. I would recommend using JSHint. Have a dev configuration that allows `debugger` and a prod configuration that doesn't.

Comment: @Andy I 100% agree, but human error is unavoidable. Thanks I'll look into JSHint as this is not currently part of the deployment process. However I'm still after a fail-safe which prevents `debugger` in a live environment, if it does manage to slip through the cracks.

Comment: If you use git you could introduce a pre-commit process that does a grep on your JS files to look for "debugger" and doesn't allow a file to be pushed to the repo if it's found.